# Software for signing a PDF file with a smart card

Tags: windows, pdf, smart-card

I am looking for a software which can sign a PDF file with a smart card.

We have two USB smart card readers available:

- Gemalto IDBridge CT 40
- ReinerSCT CyberJack

The software should mainly allow command line operation, i.e., call the software by some other tool, sign a PDF and save it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Which OS should it run on? What is your price limit?

Comment: @Izzy Windows, price is not primary crucial

Comment: @askolotl: Is 100 USD OK? Is 10.000 USD OK?

Comment: Are you looking for something that works out of the box with those card readers or something that you have to build to work with those card readers?

Answer (score 1):

For signing PDF from a web application, from Digital Signature Certificate in the user's smartcard or USB Token, you may need to use Browser Extension.  [Signer.Digital](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/signerdigital/glghokcicpikglmflbbelbgeafpijkkf) browser extension (provided by my company) is free to use.

You may refer to [Working Sample](https://web.signer.digital) of the Signer.Digital browser extension. Developers can use Signer.Digital extension for free to integrate digital signing of PDF, XML, Json, or any content from their web application.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for smartcard based signing, I recommend you go through the list of [OpenSC based applications](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Using-smart-cards-with-applications). OpenSC is the base library of most applications using smartcard and USB key hardware certificates.

At first glance, the following seem interesting for your use case (though I haven't tried any of them so far):

- [j4sign](http://j4sign.sourceforge.net/), still in active development, and Java based so it should be able to run under Windows
- [Sinadura](http://www.sinadura.net/en/inicio)
- [cryptonit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptonit/)